# How do I convert an AnsiChar to a WideChar?

Tags: string, delphi, winapi, unicode

I have for example the AnsiChar "A" and I would like to convert it to a widechar (without typecasting it!). I was thinking about some memory operations but I don't know how an AnsiChar would look like in a WideChar (in memory). Maybe there's also a WinAPI Command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's wrong with typecasting?

It works if you do it, but I'll tell you why it's wrong further down this post. :p

```
var
  A: AnsiChar;
  B: WideChar;
begin
  A := 'a';
  B := WideChar(A);
```

**About ANSI and ASCII (and UCS-2)**

AnsiChars are single byte characters. WideChars are double byte characters with UCS-2 encoding, which is a subset of UTF-16.

This means that for the first 127 ANSI characters (which is the ASCII character set, containing most characters know in plain english) is almost the same, except it is 2 bytes instead of one. So capital 'A' which has a byte value of $40 (hex) in ASCII, becomes the bytes $00 + $40 as a WideChar. They are just zero-padded.

For the upper half of the ANSI set this is not so easy, because those characters can have different meaning, depending on the code page used. This range can contain greek characters, western european characters (like é) or other characters, but not a combination of all, since there's only room for 128 characters in that range. So to convert ANSI to WideChar, you'll have to know (or assume) the code page. All (or most) of those code pages are have a different position in the total range of the 65536 different characters that are supported by widechar.

**About the typecast**

That said, I can put a é in the code fragment above and it still works, accidentally. Delphi actually just converts the byte value to a double byte value, so typecasting an AnsiChar to a WideChar is basically the same as assigning a Byte to a Word. There's no real conversion done. It happens to be that not only the first, 'Basic Latin' plane of UTF-16 matches ASCII, but also the second 'Latin1 supplement plane', matches the ISO 8859-1 character set that Western Europeans have in their ANSI table. Therefore, I can migrate all my texts to WideCharacters by just adding bytes with the value `0` between the existing characters.

But not all people are this lucky. If you have a Russian text in Ansi then this typecast will not work. To do that properly, make sure you have Delphi 2009 or above, which supports unicode strings and has various tools to convert between encodings and between various ANSI  code pages.

B.t.w., for AnsiChar to WideChar you need a typecast, which turns out to be a normal integer assignment after all, but you can actually assign an AnsiString to a WideString and Delphi will hide all the conversion for you, and actually compile it to a call to `_WStrFromLStr`, which is defined in the `System` unit in case you'd like to investigate how it works.

I hope this answers your specific question, but still, you might want to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). It's a very good explanation of unicode in general. In it, you'll find Ansi, ASCII and UCS-2 as I mentioned, but all placed in a little more context.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. But how would the 2 bytes look like in memory?

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss I believe most if not all the 8-bit ANSI characters are front-filled with a 0 byte. So if the 8-bit ANSI char code is `$3E`, then the `WideChar` (Unicode) value is `$003E`. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss Added a little piece of text with a little bit of explanation.

Comment: @mbratch Thank you for the info. GolezTrol I've just read it, thank you very much. This answers my question. Thank you :)

Comment: +1 for the awesome Link! Thank you very much again.

Comment: +1. Extremely well written. :-)

Comment: This clears a lot of (additional) questions that I still had in mind.

Comment: I've taken a look at what happens when you typecast AnsiChar to WideChar and what happend when you assign AnsiString to WideString. They turn out to be quite different, and I've added a paragraph about it.

Comment: *What's wrong with typecasting?* Well, it doesn't work at all because it doesn't take any account of code page.

Comment: Thanks. That about sums up my answer. :p

Comment: Well, there are a number of flaws in your answer in my view. The whole tenor of the answer reflects your original revision which asserted that a type case suffices. You are incorrect when you say that a WideChar represents a UCS2 encoded character. Nowadays, Windows is UTF-16 and a WideChar represents a BMP character, or one half of a surrogate pair. The discussion of ISO 8859-1 is mis-placed. Windows ANSI is quite different. Finally you don't cover how to convert from MBCS to WideChar, no mention of `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Answer (score 8):

The Windows API function MultiByteToWideChar is provided to perform this conversion. Naturally you need to specify the codepage of the input data. For example:

```
function AnsiCharToWideChar(ac: AnsiChar; CodePage: UINT): WideChar;
begin
  if MultiByteToWideChar(CodePage, 0, @ac, 1, @Result, 1) <> 1 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Note that all the characters that are defined in the ANSI code pages map to Unicode characters from the Basic Multilingual Plane and so are represented by a single UTF-16 character. Hence the size assumptions of the code above.

However, the assumption that you are making, and that this answer persists, is that a single byte represents a character in an ANSI character set. That's a valid assumption for many character sets, for example the single byte western character sets like 1252. But there are character sets like 932 (Japanese), 949 (Koren) etc. that are double byte character sets. Your entire approach, and the code above, breaks down for those code pages.

Comment: A single byte *does* refer to a character in an ANSI character set. Code page `932` and `949` are code pages, but not actually ANSI code pages, even though people tend to call them that. Microsoft did indeed invent some double byte character code pages to fit into their -by that time- only single byte OS, but these code pages require a different treatment indeed.

Comment: @GolezTrol None of the Windows ANSI code pages are actually ANSI standards. Windows 1252 is not ANSI either. They are known on Windows as ANSI and that's all I mean. Windows ANSI code pages can and do have double byte characters.